# Запрет на вставку форматированного текста в EditText

Tags: android

Если в мобильном браузере скопировать какой-нибудь текст сайта с ссылками в буфер обмена и затем вставить в EditText, то текст будет форматированным, подчеркнутый, с разными цветами. Как можно запретить такое поведение для EditText, а просто вставить текст без форматирования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сделать собственный класс наследующий от `EditText`, в котором перегрузить метод `onTextContextMenuItem()`, типа:

```
@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
   if(id==android.R.id.paste) {
         ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
         // извлекаем чистые текстовые данные
         if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
                ClipData clipData = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
                String clipText = clipData
                        .getItemAt(clipData.getItemCount() - 1)
                        .coerceToText(context).toString();
         ClipData newClipData = new ClipData(new ClipDescription(
                                    "text",
                                    new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }),
                            new ClipData.Item(clipText));
        //помещаем текст в клипборд
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(newClipData);
        // выполняем вставку
        return super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если попробовать так:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        CharacterStyle[] toBeRemovedSpans = string.getSpans(0, string.length(),
            MetricAffectingSpan.class);
        for (int index = 0; index < toBeRemovedSpans; index++)
            string.removeSpan(toBeRemovedSpans[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо вам 
сделать так

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

или можно так но эт глобально

- зайти в настройки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Отключить проверку правописания

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но мне не проверка на правописание нужна, а именно форматирование текста, например, откройте статью википедию в мобильном браузере, выделите весь текст, скопируйте и вставьте в EditText, вы увидите, что все ссылки из статьи отображаются подчеркиванием, мне бы хотелось этого избежать.

Comment: @cooper_so android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
вы это сделали и не помогли?

Comment: Да попробовал, к сожалению, не помогло